# Intersection of an $n-$sphere and a plane (when non-empty and not a point)

Tags: geometry, circles

Let the n-sphere of radius $r$ centered at $(0,0,...,0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be defined by
$$
\mathcal{S} \iff {x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 + ... + {x_n}^2 + (x_{n+1}-y)^2 = r^2
$$
and consider the function $d$ which to any point in the unit-ball $B(0,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ associates the dependent coordinate $x_{n+1}\leq y$ in the lower hemisphere of $\mathcal{S}$:
$$
d\ :\ v\in B(0,r)\ \mapsto\ y -\sqrt{r^2 - \|v\|^2}
$$

For a given $v = (v_1,...,v_n)\in B(0,r)$, consider now the function 
$$
\forall t\in I_v\subset\mathbb{R},\quad \psi_v(t) = \big( tv_1, tv_2, ..., tv_n, d(tv) \big)
$$

Is the image of $\psi_v$ a circle?

Comment: I don't understand what your function $d$ is, could you please clarify? Why are you talking about an n-sphere when $d$ a projection of $R^n$? How do you define "lower"?

Comment: I'm referring to the $n-sphere$ defined as the set of $x$ satisfying $x_{1}^{2}+...+(y- x_{n+1})^{2}=r^{2}$. By lower I mean $d(x_{1},...,x_{n})=y-\sqrt(r^{2} - (x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2}))$. Does that clarify?

Comment: Actually, I see that this gives $\psi(t)= y- \sqrt(r^{2} - t^{2}v^{2})$, which is the bottom half of an ellipse...

Comment: So if I take $|v|=1$ I will get a circle

Comment: You won't get an ellipse, as defined above $\psi$ is always a half circle (cf my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $d$ and for a given $v$, the image of $\psi_v$ will always be a half-circle of radius $r$ centered at $y$ in the plane $(x-y)\cdot(\psi_v(0)\wedge\psi_v(1)) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you Sh3ljohn. Will we get a half circle in the following case as well? Let $w = (w_1,...,w_n) \neq 0 \in B(0,r)$. For a given $v = (v_1,...,v_n)\in B(0,r)$, consider now the function 
$$
\forall t\in I_v\subset\mathbb{R},\quad \psi_{v,w}(t) = \big( w_1 + tv_1, w_2 + tv_2, ..., w_n +tv_n, d(w+tv) \big)
$$

Comment: Good question, I have to think about this :) I have to leave but I'll answer.

Comment: ALright, thanks!

Comment: @Pilot My mistake sorry, you are right! So provided that $t$ is in a suitable domain (such that $(w+tv)\in B(0,r) \forall t$), you have a half-circle again then, of radius $\sqrt{ \|w\|^2 + d(w)^2 }$. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: Oh okay, great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pilot Sorry, my previous radius is wrong I'm afraid... It's not as simple as taking $t=0$ because the domain of $t$ is not symmetric. My apologies..

Comment: Yes, no worries, I just noticed that too. If |v|=1, I think the radius is: $\sqrt(r^2 -|w|^2 -2<w,v>^2)$. I got this by just rewriting d(w+tv).